# Centering the text inside select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a select element in my HTML form and by default, the text is aligned left. `text-align: center;` does not center it like a text input.

From other answers on Stack Overflow, some users say to use the `text-indent` property but though it moves the text, it isn't good for aligning different lengths of text.

Though a CSS would be best, a javascript/jQuery solution would be okay.

So finally, how do I go about centering the text in a form select element?

**HTML Code:**

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML code

Comment: There is not really any special HTML code is post though I will if you'd like.

Comment: @PavSidhu do You want all options to be centered or just selected one, which will be showed after select?

Answer (score -2):

**HTML:**

```
<select name="country">
<option value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
```

**CSS:**

```
   select {

    height: 37px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KnowledgeGuard/P5k4D/196/)

if you do not want to pad the eliment you could always use a  Javascript-based  extension which typically uses `<div>` elements instead of an actual `<select>` element and allows you to easily style it.

https://formstone.it/components/dropdown/#options

Comment: Won't this just indent things like `text-indent`?

Comment: Still not centered - just indented with padding on both sides.

Comment: text-align applies to block level elements only. But
even if you assign display: block to the select and option elements,
the texts probably won't be centered. The reason is that browsers use
their built-in routines for rendering form fields, and these routines
are affected by CSS rules to a limited extent only.you have to use an indent of some kind. you can change it to align right with <select dir="rtl" name="country">